# How do you play these ukelele tabs?

Tags: notation, tablature, ukulele

I'm trying to learn ukelele, following the tablerature given here:
http://www.ukulele-tabs.com/uke-songs/cake/commissioning-a-symphony-in-c-uke-tab-1909.html

I can do the first verse, which has the chords indicated with the words.  And I'm guessing that the second verse follows the same pattern.   How does that second group of chords fit in-- is it on its own (there's a bit in the song w/o words there), or associated with another verse? (if so, how?)

There are a couple of verses in the song with six lines, rather than four.  How does the music fit to these?

Comment: Great song! The site won't show UK clients the tab. Perhaps you could quote the problematic part. It would also protect the question against link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't view the page, but chords for ukes are no different from chords for any other instrument, so I'm going to assume that you mean this bit (from a guitar site):

```
...
This magnificent symphony in c
Youll be commissioning a symphony in c

F C Dm G C... F C 
G C...

Completely filling the palace concert hall
Its warm and golden like an oven thats wide open
...
```

Since I know the song, I can say with confidence that these are the chords for the instrumental section leading into the next verse.

The "six line" verses are the same as the "four line" verses -- they have just had some newlines inserted.

---

Online chord sheets generally assume that the reader knows the song, and is experienced enough to hear when a chord change is needed. The format is pretty imprecise compared to a lead sheet with bar lines, repeat markers etc.

To work out what to do, you need to listen to the song.

Also take care, because many of them are inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I see the connection on further inspection-- Every two lines forms a phrase, which has either four or five different chords.  Those chords are then indicated and seperated by elipses (...)